# Is there benefit to an Anti-forgery cookie with sameSite:none?

Tags: csrf, asp.net-core

We have a form that is using asp.net core [AntiForgery validation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.antiforgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Recently encountered an issue with a form on the site hosted on `www.domain.ie` not being able to `POST` to the API at `api.domain.co.uk` due to AntiForgery validation.

The recommendation from the team who implemented this is to set `sameSite=none` on the AntiForgery token cookie.

I'm not familiar with Antiforgery validation but this seems like it would negate the purpose of using it. Is that the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it won't negate the purpose of using it since the framework's `Antiforgery validation` mechanism will remain the same. The `samesite` attribute should not replace having a CSRF Token. Instead, it should co-exist with that token in order to protect the user in a more robust way (cf. https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#samesite-cookie-attribute).

What you should keep in mind though, is:

1. Cookies with `SameSite=None` must now also specify the `Secure` attribute ([they require a secure context/HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite)).
2. [Chrome 85](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/02/samesite-cookie-changes-in-february.html) doesn't allow insecure `SameSite=None` cookies